# Function for business hours in seconds based on calendar table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm fairly new to this forum and to T-SQL.

I'm looking for a function to calculate business hours in seconds based on my calendar table. In my calendar table I have 2 columns in it. 1st column is date and opening time and 2nd column date and end time.

I tried the solution from @Ezlo [SQL Server counting hours between dates excluding Fri 6pm - Mon 6am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50905210/sql-server-counting-hours-between-dates-excluding-fri-6pm-mon-6am/58169436#58169436)
 In his solution when its the same date it doubles the time for example the output has to be 75 secs its then 150 secs. I want to be able to call the function in a query like WorkTime (@StartDate DATETIME, @FinishDate DATETIME) while it passes through my calendar table. The startdate and finishdate has to be anything I put as value in it ie a columns (datecreated,dateclosed) with dates.

Ie: a query with 1000 rows like this format.

Scenario 1

```
TicketID:    111111
DateCreated: 2019-01-01 10:00:52
DateClosed:  2019-01-02 08:35:00
```

Function result has to be 300 secs while it checked my calendar table.

Scenario 2

```
TicketID:    111112
DateCreated: 2019-01-02 16:30:00
DateClosed:  2019-01-02 16:15:00
```

Function result has to be 900 secs while it checked my calendar table.

Scenario 3

```
TicketID:    111113
DateCreated: 2019-01-02 20:00:00
DateClosed:  2019-01-03 09:30:00
```

Function result: 3600 secs

Scenario 4

```
TicketID:    111114
DateCreated: 2019-01-05 20:00:00
DateClosed:  2019-01-07 09:00:00
```

Function result: 1800 secs

**Calendar** table

[image: calendar table]

As you can see I have ie 1st of January set to 08:30 so it doesn't calculate the time (Holiday). And so I have a set of Holidays set the same way.

Weekends are left out see calendar table, in that way it is excluded and the time starts to count on the first business day.

I have tried multiple times but with no success of getting it to work as I wish.

Hopefully you gurus can me help me to achieve this.

Comment: _"I have tried multiple times"_ at least show one attempt. Have you ever search for [`DATEDIFF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: Did you write any query for this? What output did you get? What output do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of searching this forum. The answer I was looking for can be found here.
[Calculate time difference (only working hours) in minutes between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296923/calculate-time-difference-only-working-hours-in-minutes-between-two-dates?rq=1)